# Equations for infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I recently pondered about how to turn an infinite series into a graph. For example, a very simple infinite sum is just $n$. This means $1+2+3+4+\ldots$. I realized that this was quadratic and solved for the equation $\frac12x^2+\frac12x$. Now at $x=1$, the graph is $1$, at $2$ it is $3$, at $3$ it is $6$, etc. I also tried $\frac1{2^n}$ and got $2-\frac1{2^x}$. I was having trouble doing it with other formulas, such as the Leibniz formula for $\pi$ along with other complex ones. Any general suggestions on how to to find other equations equations for these series?

Answer (score 2):

As you have discovered, there are fairly convenient formulas for $\sum_{k=0}^{n}f(k)$ where $f$ is polynomial or has the form $f(x)=ab^x$.  There are other nice special cases too.  But in general, just as there are functions whose integrals have no closed form expressions, there are sequences whose associated series have no closed form expressions (and for much the same reasons).

Comment: You could add a note: "...but don't stop trying!"  One could always discover something new in mathematics, unless you've specifically proven that a sequence *cannot* have a closed form.  And since in my understanding of the phrase "closed form" that is dependent upon the notation, one could always invent more notation.  :)